# It's time for drag and drop!

Tags: feature-request, drag-and-drop

I often find myself wishing SO supported drag and drop. For example I drag a tag to my favs and it would add it, or when searching by tag I would like to drag the tag to the search box and get `[asp.net]` added in the search box.

Does it make sense to add this feature or is it just too much work for so little use?

Comment: I pine for the days when you could do **everything** with a combination of Shift,Control,Alt and TAB keys. Windows happily keeps this support (Alt+Spacebar anyone?) but its support is lacking in more "modern" programs (like internet browsers. Have you ever tried tabbing through 800 links?)

Comment: I'd prefer a command line interface.

Comment: I'd prefer punch cards.

Comment: @alex I'd prefer a butterfly interface

Comment: I'd prefer a Minority Report interface.

Comment: @Farseeker: Have you every had a website (*hint*) hijack user defined meta cords?

Answer (score 2):

Too much work for too little benefit.

Drag and drop is nice, but the time and effort you put into making it work *right* just isn't worth the outcome, which is 1% happy users and 10% confused. The other 89% didn't even notice the feature.

Comment: I highly doubt it'll take too long to make it work right. They could use any one of a number of existing libraries (eg. jQuery UI) and it probably wouldn't take more than an afternoon.

Comment: I would much rather have the work go to cooler and more useful things such as facebook like @ comment notifications and tag-completion in the search box

Comment: @waiwai, don't you mean 6-8 weeks? +1, though, for suggesting they totally drop that and use jquery

Comment: @EarlZ: Screw Facebook integration.

Comment: @Josh you're thinking of a different Earlz. There is someone who has stolen the profile name of a lot of sites that goes by earlZ. My name is Earlz though. case sensitive!

Comment: @Earlz: Actually I probably just hit the shift key.

Answer (score 0):

I can see how this would make things easier in some situations, but given what is already available in the system, the situations where this would be handy are infrequently, or never, repeated.

- Interesting/ignored tags usually don't change too much, and you only add them once
- Doing a search for questions with a specific tag can already be done by clicking on the tag, and then subsequent tag clicks on the "related" tags lets you AND your search immediately with no typing. Doing a complex search is relatively rare -- if you're doing the same search that often, add a bookmark in your browser.