# Should "Search Options" help text (tips?) include description of how to "AND" tags to existing search?

Tags: discussion, hidden-features

While searching for something else I came upon an [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50125/its-time-for-drag-and-drop/50132#50132) to a question which described a tag feature I was previously unaware of.

*Doing a search for questions with a specific tag can already be done by clicking on the tag, and then subsequent tag `clicks on the "related" tags lets you AND your search immediately with no typing`.*

This does not appear to be covered by the ["Search Options"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search) page which provides more details on how to use the Stack Exchange search function.

Suggestions for enhancing how tags are entered into the search field seems to be a frequent question in meta. Shouldn't as many as possible of the "tips and tricks" one can use when searching with tags be included in "Search Options"? (Or at least this one? :)

(I am referring to the page displayed when one does an empty search on any (I think?) of the Stack Exchange sites. This Search Options page is the only SE search documentation which I am familiar with, so if this feature is already described somewhere else please just point me in that direction.)

BTW, I noticed that while the "Search Results" page includes the help text `Want better search results? See our search tips!`, this does not seem to be displayed on the "Tagged Questions" page shown when one searches with tags.

I could not think of any reason why the link to the help info would not also be potentially useful when searching with tags. Is this intentional?