# Dragging and dropping a tag into the Edit Favorite Tags textbox

Tags: feature-request, tags, tag-watching

It may be wrong on my behalf to assume the following behavior as correct but:

I'd would expect to be able to drag and drop (*instead of typing*) any tag into the favorites tags textbox.

Dragging and dropping any tag into the TextBox while editing the favorite tags section should fill in the textbox with the text from the tag.

[image]

So for example, if I grab a [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) and drop it in the Textbox I would want the textbox to display `C#` instead of

`http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23`

Comment: What you currently experience is browser behavior: on dragging and dropping a link, it paste its `href`.

Comment: And also requested [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/50125/152859).

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd you're right. Good point. Do you think that's overridable with some client side JS?

Comment: Sure it's overrideable, question is "is it worth the developer's time and effort?" and on this only the team can answer.

Comment: right, Ok voted to close as a duplicate.